# Create folder and save image into this folder that is send from android application

Tags: php, android

I have following PHP code to create a folder and save an image into this generated folder. What works is the generation of the folder, but the associated image will not be inserted into the folder, so the folder is always empty:

```
            $uid = $_POST['uid'];
            $image = $_POST["image"];

            $suffix = $db->createRandomID(); //function creates random numbers and stores in $suffix
            $url = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX/uploads_offer/";
            $image_name = "img_offer_".$suffix."".$uid."_".date("Y-m-d-H-m-s").".jpg";
            $path = $url."".$image_name; // path of saved image 


            // base64 encoded utf-8 string
            $binary2 = base64_decode($image);

            // binary, utf-8 bytes
            header("Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8");

            $filepath = $image_name; 


            if (file_exists("../uploads_offer/".$uid)){
                //$file = fopen("../uploads_offer/".$uid . $image_name, "wb");
                $file = fopen("../uploads_offer".$uid.$image_name, "wb");
                fwrite($file, $binary2);
                fclose($file);

            }else{
                $result8 = mkdir("../uploads_offer/".$uid, 0755);
                $file = fopen("../uploads_offer".$uid.$image_name, "wb");
                fwrite($file, $binary2);
                fclose($file);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing slashes (`/`) in your `fopen()` calls:

```
$file = fopen("../uploads_offer/".$uid."/".$image_name, "wb");
```